# Hadoop copy from cluster to cluster fails due to "Mismatch in length of source"

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2, distcp

I want to copy data from one to another cluster. I use this command

```
hadoop distcp hdfs://SOURCE-NAMENODE:9000/dir/ \ hdfs://DESTINATION-NAMENODE:9000/
```

And I get this message:

> 18/04/11 12:05:37 INFO mapred.CopyMapper: Copying
>   hdfs://SOURCE-NAMENODE:9000/SOURCE-NAMENODE/WALs/xxxx,18560,1523039740289/xxxx%2C18560%2C1523039740289.default.1523445499108
>   to
>   hdfs://DESTINATION-NAMENODE:9000/SOURCE-NAMENODE/WALs/xxxx,18560,1523039740289/xxxx%2C18560%2C1523039740289.default.1523445499108
>   18/04/11 12:05:37 INFO mapred.RetriableFileCopyCommand: Creating temp
>   file:
>   hdfs://DESTINATION-NAMENODE:9000/.distcp.tmp.attempt_local2084770019_0001_m_000000_0
>   18/04/11 12:05:38 ERROR util.RetriableCommand: Failure in Retriable
>   command: Copying
>   hdfs://SOURCE-NAMENODE:9000/SOURCE-NAMENODE/WALs/xxxx,18560,1523039740289/xxxx%2C18560%2C1523039740289.default.1523445499108
>   to
>   hdfs://DESTINATION-NAMENODE:9000/SOURCE-NAMENODE/WALs/xxxx,18560,1523039740289/xxxx%2C18560%2C1523039740289.default.1523445499108
>   java.io.IOException: Mismatch in length of
>   source:hdfs://SOURCE-NAMENODE:9000/SOURCE-NAMENODE/WALs/xxxx,18560,1523039740289/xxxx%2C18560%2C1523039740289.default.1523445499108
>   and
>   target:hdfs://DESTINATION-NAMENODE:9000/.distcp.tmp.attempt_local2084770019_0001_m_000000_0
>           at org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.RetriableFileCopyCommand.compareFileLengths(RetriableFileCopyCommand.java:193)...

On destination I only see directories created and none of files.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably due to the fact you are copying a file that's being written to.